# How to validate nullable object variable with properties

Tags: terraform

I have module like:

```
variable "client_certificate" {
  description = "Client certificate settings."

  type = object({
    enabled = bool
    mode    = string
  })

  default =  null

  validation {
    condition     = var.client_certificate == null || (var.client_certificate != null && var.client_certificate.enabled == false && var.client_certificate.mode == null)
    error_message = "The Client Certificate mode possible values include Optional, Required, Allow, Ignore."
  }
}


resource "null_resource" "display" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT

        echo "${var.client_certificate != null ? var.client_certificate.mode : "siema"}"
        
    EOT
  }
}
```

And I want to be avle to provide `client_certificate`  as null, but also be able to verify properties via validation mechanism.

I call it:

```
module "display" {
  source = "./modulek"

  client_certificate          =  null
}
```

but then I got:

```
│ Error: Attempt to get attribute from null value
│
│   on modulek\main.tf line 12, in variable "client_certificate":
│   12:     condition     = var.client_certificate != null && var.client_certificate.enabled == false && var.client_certificate.mode == null
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.client_certificate is null
│
│ This value is null, so it does not have any attributes.
╵
╷
│ Error: Attempt to get attribute from null value
│
│   on modulek\main.tf line 12, in variable "client_certificate":
│   12:     condition     = var.client_certificate != null && var.client_certificate.enabled == false && var.client_certificate.mode == null
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.client_certificate is null
│
│ This value is null, so it does not have any attributes.
```

For me this is really strange because I was assuming that `var.client_certificate == null` should finish evaluation of condition as it provides true. But I was wrong, and whole expression is evaluated. Since that I'm not sure how I could overcome this. I tried with lookup, but it was the same.

Comment: Try removing `default =  null`.

Comment: I made mistake writing question. In second snipper it should be `  client_certificate          =  null` as I want to be able to pass null there. Removing default dosn't help here - I checked it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`null` objects do not have `enabled` nor `mode` fields. Thus you get those errors. You have to use [try](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/try).

I'm not exactly sure what you want your condition to exactly be, but you can try with:

```
    condition     = try((var.client_certificate == null || (var.client_certificate != null && var.client_certificate.enabled == false && var.client_certificate.mode == null)), false)
```

Comment: I know that  object with null value doesn't have properties set ;) But normally when you have condition like `condition1 or condition2`, the condition2 doesn't matter when first one is evaluated to true. But here is looks like it tokenize first whole condition, a then tries to replace a token with value behind. And after that evaluates condition.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej Yes. Therefore, you can use `try`.

Answer (score 1):

Terraform does not short-circuit logical evaluation. It will always evaluate all branches and conditions.
Therefore using simple guard condition won't work, however ternary operator ?: can can be used instead with only moderately worsened readability

`condition = var.client_certificate == null ? true : (var.client_certificate.enabled == false && var.client_certificate.mode == null)`